# Android - NDK strange error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I start getting funny errors with NDK with fairly complex program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    return 0;
}


>call c:\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build.cmd
"Compile++ thumb : test <= test.cpp
In file included from C:/workspace/c++11_test//jni/test.cpp:11:
In file included from c:/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport\iostream:43:
In file included from c:/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport\stl/_istream.h:31:
In file included from c:/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport\stl/_ostream.h:380:
In file included from c:/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport\stl/_ostream.c:26:
In file included from c:/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport\stl/_num_put.h:180:
In file included from c:/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport\stl/_num_put.c:26:
c:/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport\stl/_limits.h:217:48: error: non-type template argument evaluates to -2147483648, which cannot be narrowed to type 'wchar_t'
      [-Wc++11-narrowing]
  : public _STLP_PRIV _Integer_limits<wchar_t, WCHAR_MIN, WCHAR_MAX, -1, true>
                                               ^
c:/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include\../include/wchar.h:76:22: note: expanded from macro 'WCHAR_MIN'
#define  WCHAR_MIN   INT_MIN
                     ^
c:/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include\sys/limits.h:69:18: note: expanded from macro 'INT_MIN'
#define INT_MIN         (-0x7fffffff-1) /* min value for an int */
                        ^
1 error generated.
```

### make: *** [C:/workspace/c++11_test//obj/local/armeabi/objs/test/test.o] Error 1

It's **ndk-r9**. **4.8** complie it just fine, only **clang** stumbles on it.
Do I need to define something to make clang work?
I've tried to Google errors, but got nothing relevant...
Obviously, I can turn it off with **-Wno-c++11-narrowing**, but I don't want disable narrowing checks.

And it's only shows with **stlport_static**, there is NO error with **gnustl_static**

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have enabled C++11, since you are getting this warning.

STLport support for C++11 is not very good. I suspect this is the reason for your woes.

A fix requires changes to STLport, or removing the "-std=c++11" switch from the clang command-line.

IMHO, I would recommend switching to the gnustl (aka. libstdc++), unless there are other reasons that prevent you from doing so (licensing: libstdc++ is [GPL3 with some significant exceptions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/license.html#manual.intro.status.license.gpl) that may or may not be valid for clang - you should determine that for yourself), legacy support, size etc.). I have had very good experiences with that.